# Calculator will not find row reduced echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, calculator

I have a TI-84 Plus CE which I am using to find the row reduced echelon form of matrices. It has worked well so far, but it gives me an "Invalid Dimension" error for this matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\\ 3 & 6\\\ 2&4\end{pmatrix}$$
Now it seems evident to me that the row reduced echelon form is $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\\ 0 & 0\\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ so why can my calculator not find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/rref:

> The rref( command can be used to solve a system of linear equations.
>   First, take each equation, in the standard form of $a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n=b$, and
>   put the coefficients into a row of the matrix.
>
> Then, use rref( on the matrix. There are three possibilities now:
>
> - If the system is solvable, the left part of the result will look like
>     the identity matrix. Then, the final column of the matrix will contain
>     the values of the variables.
> - If the system is inconsistent, and has no
>     solution, then it will end with rows that are all 0 except for the
>     last entry.
> - If the system has infinitely many solutions, it will end
>     with rows that are all 0, including the last entry.
>
> [ERR:INVALID DIM](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/errors#invaliddim) is thrown if the matrix has more rows than columns.

---

**One thing I'd recommend doing is just adding columns of $0$'s until you have a square matrix. Then, the program will row reduce as normal and you can ignore the extra columns.**

Comment: I have edited your answer to make it clear which parts are directly taken from another source...

Comment: @Misha Lavrov can you tell me how you put that in yellow?

Comment: It's the `>` marks at the beginning of each line - if you click the "edit" button again, you will see exactly the Markdown syntax that produces these results.

Comment: @MishaLavrov so when im quoting material i just stick a > in front of each line

Comment: Yep. You can also select some text and press the quotation mark button at the top of the text box to automatically insert them.